# qml: Rectangle animation not working

Tags: qt, qml

I have an application, where I want to apply an animation to a button/ rectangle and after this executes the animation, it should display a dialog. The problem is that when the dialog.visible: true is called on onClicked, the animation is not executed. I have created a test application here are the two qml files:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    FileDialogs
    {
        id:fileDialog
        visible:false
        width:800
        height:800
        //modality: Qt.WindowModal
        z:10
    }

    Rectangle
    {
        id:rect
        width:200
        height:200
        color:"blue"
        Text
        {
            id:simpleText
            text:"This is a button"
            font.pixelSize: 20
            color:"white"
            width:200
            height:200
        }

        states: [
                State {
                    name: "PRESSED"
                },
                State {
                    name: "RELEASED"
                }
            ]
        transitions: [
                Transition {
                    from: "PRESSED"
                    to: "RELEASED"
                    PropertyAnimation { id: selectAnim; target: rect; properties: "scale"; easing.type: Easing.OutBack; easing.amplitude: 3.0; easing.period: 1.5; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 400 }
                }
        ]
        MouseArea {
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  onPressed:
                  {
                      parent.state = "PRESSED"
                  }
                  onReleased:
                  {
                      parent.state = "RELEASED"
                  }
                  onClicked: {
                      fileDialog.visible=true;
                  }
              }
    }
}
```

FileDialogs.qml, from Qt examples

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Item {
    width: 580
    height: 400
    SystemPalette { id: palette }
    clip: true

    //! [filedialog]
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        visible: fileDialogVisible.checked
        modality: Qt.WindowModal
        title: fileDialogSelectFolder.checked ? "Choose a folder" :
        (fileDialogSelectMultiple.checked ? "Choose some files" : "Choose a file")
        selectExisting: fileDialogSelectExisting.checked
        selectMultiple: fileDialogSelectMultiple.checked
        selectFolder: fileDialogSelectFolder.checked
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.png *.jpg)", "All files (*)" ]
        selectedNameFilter: "All files (*)"
        sidebarVisible: fileDialogSidebarVisible.checked
        onAccepted: {
            console.log("Accepted: " + fileUrls)
            if (fileDialogOpenFiles.checked)
                for (var i = 0; i < fileUrls.length; ++i)
                    Qt.openUrlExternally(fileUrls[i])
        }
        onRejected: { console.log("Rejected") }
    }
    //! [filedialog]

    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            top: parent.top
            bottom: bottomBar.top
            leftMargin: 12
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            spacing: 8
            Item { Layout.preferredHeight: 4 } // padding
            Label {
                font.bold: true
                text: "File dialog properties:"
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogModal
                text: "Modal"
                checked: true
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.modality != Qt.NonModal }
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogSelectFolder
                text: "Select Folder"
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.selectFolder }
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogSelectExisting
                text: "Select Existing Files"
                checked: true
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.selectExisting }
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogSelectMultiple
                text: "Select Multiple Files"
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.selectMultiple }
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogOpenFiles
                text: "Open Files After Accepting"
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogSidebarVisible
                text: "Show Sidebar"
                checked: fileDialog.sidebarVisible
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.sidebarVisible }
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: fileDialogVisible
                text: "Visible"
                Binding on checked { value: fileDialog.visible }
            }
            Label {
                text: "<b>current view folder:</b> " + fileDialog.folder
            }
            Label {
                text: "<b>name filters:</b> {" + fileDialog.nameFilters + "}"
            }
            Label {
                text: "<b>current filter:</b>" + fileDialog.selectedNameFilter
            }
            Label {
                text: "<b>chosen files:</b> " + fileDialog.fileUrls
            }
            Label {
                text: "<b>chosen single path:</b> " + fileDialog.fileUrl
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: bottomBar
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        height: buttonRow.height * 1.2
        color: Qt.darker(palette.window, 1.1)
        border.color: Qt.darker(palette.window, 1.3)
        Row {
            id: buttonRow
            spacing: 6
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 12
            height: implicitHeight
            width: parent.width
            Button {
                text: "Open"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                onClicked: fileDialog.open()
            }
            Button {
                text: "Pictures"
                tooltip: "go to my Pictures directory"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                enabled: fileDialog.shortcuts.hasOwnProperty("pictures")
                onClicked: fileDialog.folder = fileDialog.shortcuts.pictures
            }
            Button {
                text: "Home"
                tooltip: "go to my home directory"
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                enabled: fileDialog.shortcuts.hasOwnProperty("home")
                onClicked: fileDialog.folder = fileDialog.shortcuts.home
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation is happening. It's just the FileDialog is covering the button before you can see it animate. Release the mouse click outside the button area and you'll see the animation (this way onClicked is not triggered).

A way to show the dialog after the animation:

```
    states: [
        State {
            name: "PRESSED"
        },
        State {
            name: "RELEASED"
        }
    ]
    transitions: [
        Transition {
            from: "PRESSED"
            to: "RELEASED"
            PropertyAnimation { id: selectAnim; target: rect; properties: "scale"; easing.type: Easing.OutBack; easing.amplitude: 3.0; easing.period: 1.5; from: 0; to: 1; duration: 400 }
            onRunningChanged: {
                if (!running) {
                    fileDialog.visible = true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed:
        {
            parent.state = "PRESSED"
        }
        onClicked: {
            parent.state = "RELEASED"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The way I display the dialog is not hiding the button. Apart from that, do you know how I can display the animate just before the dialog is shown?

Comment: It is hiding the button in the example code provided. There are many ways to do what you want. See my update for one way of doing so.